# DatagridView link to DB that change when user write in a textbox

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, datagridview

I want to link a textbox with a datagridview so that when a user type "B" in the textbox, the datagridview will show all data beginning by "B". If the user then type "B1", it will show dynamically without clicking on a button the data beginning by "B1". Wish i'm clear on that.

For the moment, 1) i need to fully type the name of the data i want to retrieve (so just typing "B0" doesnt work), 2) i need to click on a button.

Here is my code :

```
public partial class Repair : Form
{


    public Repair()
    {
        InitializeComponent();



    }



    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        SqlConnection maConnexion = new SqlConnection("Server= localhost; Database= Seica_Takaya;Integrated Security = SSPI; ");

        maConnexion.Open();

        string Var1 = textBox1.Text;
        SqlCommand command = maConnexion.CreateCommand();
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BoardName", Var1);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Machine", Var1);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SerialNum", Var1);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FComponent", Var1);
        command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM FailOnly WHERE BoardName=@BoardName OR Machine=@Machine OR SerialNum=@SerialNum OR FComponent=@FComponent AND ReportingOperator != NULL";
        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        sda.Fill(ds);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];


        //SqlConnection maConnexion = new SqlConnection("Server= localhost; Database= Seica_Takaya;Integrated Security = SSPI; ");
        //string Var1 = textBox1.Text;
        //SqlCommand command = maConnexion.CreateCommand();
        //command.CommandText = "SELECT BoardName FROM FailOnly WHERE BoardName LIKE '%" + Var1 + "%' OR Machine LIKE '%" + Var1 + "%' OR SerialNum LIKE '%" + Var1 + "%'";
        //DataSet datasetSQL = new DataSet();
        //SqlDataAdapter dataSQL = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
        //maConnexion.Open();
        //dataSQL.Fill(datasetSQL); 


    }



    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        this.Hide();
        Main ff = new Main();
        ff.Show();




    }

    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       /**
        BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
        bs.DataSource = dataGridView1.DataSource;
        bs.Filter = string.Format("BoardName LIKE '%{0}%'",textBox1.Text.Replace("'","''"));
        dataGridView1.DataSource = bs;**/





    }
}
```

Here is the result : 
[First](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PzyAv.png)

Thank you really much !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do what you are doing in **button1_Click** inside the **TextChanged** Event

You have to use the **SQL LIKE** operator to get the matching data. you can read more about the LIKE operator [Here](https://www.w3schools.com/SQL/sql_like.asp)

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
     SqlConnection maConnexion = new SqlConnection("Server= localhost; Database= Seica_Takaya;Integrated Security = SSPI; ");

        if(textBox1.Text!="")
        {
        maConnexion.Open();

        string Var1 = textBox1.Text;
        SqlCommand command = maConnexion.CreateCommand();
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BoardName", Var1 + "%");
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Machine", Var1 + "%");
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SerialNum", Var1 + "%");
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FComponent", Var1 + "%");
        command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM FailOnly WHERE BoardName LIKE @BoardName OR Machine LIKE @Machine OR SerialNum LIKE @SerialNum OR FComponent LIKE @FComponent AND ReportingOperator != NULL";
        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        sda.Fill(ds);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
maConnexion.Close();
    }

    }
```

Comment: Okay i don't get it. I've already done this with LIKE and % except i wasnt using command.parameters and the LIKE and % were put harshely in the query and it wasnt working. I've tried with bindingsource and it didnt work too. What kind of magic is this. But thanks a lot. EDIT : Oh maybe it's because of the IF that i didnt had before?

Comment: which IF are you referring to? and `the LIKE and % were put harshely in the query`, did you enclose it withing quotes like this ? `Boardname like '" + Var1 + "%'" `?

Comment: The "If (textbox1.test !="")". Maybe yeah i've failed on the quotes.